# git log <filename> doesn't show commit, but git log shows commit that edited the file

Tags: git, logging, show, commit

I discovered this odd issue while looking for a lost change.

I typed in:

```
git log httpd.conf
```

I am getting a bunch of commit hashes as expected, but not the one I did.

When I type in:

```
git log
```

I see the commit I made. When I run:

```
git show <hash>
```

I see my edits to httpd.conf

Can anyone explain what may have happened? If there is more information needed to discover the root please let me know.

Comment: Can you put in some more details. Which branch are you working on? What  are the changes lost and how? Put in some dummy data for the actuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From git docs (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

**Default mode** - simplifies the history to the simplest history explaining the final state of the tree. Simplest because it prunes some side branches if the end result is the same (i.e. merging branches with the same content)

Try using:

> git log --full-history

(Same as the default mode, but does not prune some history.)

Comment: Thank you! I am able to see the commits. So essentially, because all changes from the commit were overwritten and only existed for a period of time, Git log in default mode prunes those commits, as they are currently not affecting the state for the tree?