# --full-history flag in TortoiseGit Show Log

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using git + tortoisegit. 
When I see show log of repository I see my commit that has file1. 
But when I show log of file1 I cannot see this commit in the log history.

According to this advace [git log <filename> doesn't show commit, but git log shows commit that edited the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303805/git-log-filename-doesnt-show-commit-but-git-log-shows-commit-that-edited-the?answertab=votes#tab-top)
I use --full-history flag (git log --full-history --author-date-order file1) in the console and this command shows my commit.

How can I apply this flag when  I try to see log by tortoisegit on particular file?

Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/1048 might be interesting for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Revision log](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html) or [Reference log](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-update.html)

Hope this helped, comment if you need more.

Comment: thank you for your feedback, but I need get info for particular file but as far as I know it isn't imposibble for Revision log or Reference log on the tortoisegit.

Comment: If you read the revision log link, you find an option to check the file diff but I am not sure about the full log history over a file.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.12.3 you can enable "--full-history" using the "view" button on the log dialog. The selection will be remembered automatically.